# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3 ... using pysqlcipher3 or sqlcipher3

Tags: python, sqlite, dllimport, sqlcipher, pysqlcipher

i am trying to use pysqlcipher3 module and keep getting an error when running this line :

```
from pysqlcipher3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
```

the error i get is

```
from pysqlcipher3._sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

i built sqlcipher  and its working and i built the pysqlcipher3 following the instructions in the github page (with no erros) but i keep getting the error above when trying to actually use it.
i get the same problem with sqlcipher3 module

i am using Python 3.9.12 on windows x64 and i am not using anaconda or any virtual environment